# Download file from .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a simple application that downloads a file from .aspx page.

https://compx.com/GetFile.cfu.aspx?FileID=137&FileName=testing.pdf

from my understanding, the page handler takes the FileID and FileName in the query string to retrieve the file from the server and downloads it to the client computer.

If I use the url in the web browser I am able to download the file.

I would like to mimic the same behavior in my c# application and download the file.

The following code did not provide any response. Please help.

```
string URL = "https://helloworld/GetFile.cfu.aspx?FileID=137&FileName=testing.pdf"
WebResponse objResponse;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.ContentType = "application/PDF";
objResponse = WebRequest.Create(URL).GetResponse();
```

Comment: Assuming you've looked through http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2512241 it is unclear why you are not showing complete sample and url that matches one in your question... Please also clarify what "did not provide any response" means as `GetResponse` can't return such thing.

Comment: Is it a desktop application or a web application? Your question subject and tags contradicts

Comment: You probably should consider implementing Web Service to serve your purpose. Best regards,

Comment: You should probably consider reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx). What does `GetResponse` return?

Answer (score 3):

Use the DownloadFile method of the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) class:

```
using System.Net;
//...
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("https://compx.com/GetFile.cfu.aspx?FileID=137&FileName=testing.pdf", @"C:\testing.pdf");
```

Comment: Definitely the right call. Don't forget to Dispose() that client object properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to msdn:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1]

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
```

you need to read the file content from stream and save it to your local path.